# python time string does not match format

Tags: python, string, datetime, date-parsing

```
def deadlines(t):
    '''shows pretty time to deadlines'''
    fmt = '%a %d %m %Y %I:%M %p %Z' 

    dt = datetime.strptime( t , fmt )

    print 'dt ', repr(dt)


first = 'Sun 11 May 2014 05:00 PM PDT'
deadlines(first)
```

> ValueError: time data 'Sun 11 May 2014 02:00 PM PDT' does not match format ' %a %d %m %Y %I:%M %p %Z '

Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%m` matches months represent as a two-digit decimal (in `[01, 12]`). Use `%b` for abbreviated month names, or `%B` for full month names instead:

```
fmt = '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M %p %Z'
```

A table showing the date format directives and their meanings can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

---

**If you're having trouble parsing `PDT` using `%Z`:**

Per the [time.strptime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime):

> Support for the %Z directive is based on the values contained in
>   tzname and whether daylight is true. Because of this, it is
>   platform-specific except for recognizing UTC and GMT which are always
>   known (and are considered to be non-daylight savings timezones).

So, if parsing the date string without PDT works:

```
In [73]: datetime.strptime('Sun 11 May 2014 05:00 PM', '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M %p')
Out[73]: datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 11, 17, 0)
```

but

```
datetime.strptime('Sun 11 May 2014 05:00 PM PDT', '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M %p %Z')
```

raises a ValueError, then you may need strip off the timezone name (they are, [in general, ambiguous anyway](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2013-March/018827.html)):

```
In [10]: datestring = 'Sun 11 May 2014 05:00 PM PDT'

In [11]: datestring, _ = datestring.rsplit(' ', 1)

In [12]: datestring
Out[12]: 'Sun 11 May 2014 05:00 PM'

In [13]: datetime.strptime(datestring, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M %p')
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 11, 17, 0)
```

or use [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
In [1]: import dateutil.parser as parser

In [2]: parser.parse('Sun 11 May 2014 05:00 PM PDT')
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 11, 17, 0)
```

Comment: +1 for dateutil.parser.parse.  It handles almost every intuitive case you can think of without any extra work.

Comment: It should be noted that dateutil's parser takes an argument `tzinfos` which allows you to supply a dict that maps abbreviations like `PDT` to a proper time zone name. Parsing to naive datetime seems wrong to me.