# Python - Error in parsing date

Tags: python

Trying to parse a date to a string and getting this error. Not able to figure out which variable is incorrect.

> ValueError: time data '12:00 AM IST on June 01, 2017' does not match
>   format '%I:%M %p %Z on %B %d, %Y'

Here is the code

```
data = sorted(data['data'], key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date']['pretty'], '%I:%M %p %Z on %B %d, %Y'), reverse=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `strftime` to see if you can recreate your date data with your format code?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704862/1609514) regarding the `%Z` timezone directive.

Comment: Replacing IST with UTC works - so this is definitely something to do with time zones.

Comment: What is `IST` supposed to refer to? Irish Standard Time, India Standard Time, Israel Standard Time, etc?  A proper time stamp would use an offset from UTC, not a text label, to designate a timezone.

Comment: @chepner Indian Standard Time. I receive this time data from an external api call which returns a time data in this format. Ill strip the 'IST' part of it as i dont need it further in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)** might help you

**Demo:**

```
from dateutil import parser
s = '12:00 AM IST on June 01, 2017'
print(parser.parse(s))
```

**Output:**

```
2017-06-01 00:00:00
```

**Note:** The issue you are having is with converting the zone `IST`

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not the timezone information is maintained in the result?

Comment: I tried. Not able to get the zone `parser.parse(s).strftime("%Y/ %Z")` == `2017/ `

Comment: Then surely `datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M %p IST on %B %d, %Y')` is a better idea?

Comment: @jpp. Yep that's better