# Don't understand this ValueError parsing a date string

Tags: python, strptime

For some reason python is not parsing my date properly but I looked at the [strftime/strptime behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and it looks to be right

```
import time
d = 'May 17, 2018 3:10 AM PDT'
time.mktime(time.strptime(d, "%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z"))
```

If I do:

```
time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z")
```

I get `May 18, 2018 02:47 PM EDT`, which looks to be the exact same format except for the leading 0 but `strptime` should be able to parse leading `0`s.

What am I doing wrong in parsing this date?

Edit: Found out its the timezone but not sure why:

```
time.mktime(time.strptime("May 17, 2018 3:10 AM UTC", "%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z"))
```

returns a value

```
time.mktime(time.strptime("May 17, 2018 3:10 AM PDT", "%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z"))
```

returns ValueError

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704862/7044293

Comment: It's not about the leading zeros but about the timezone - it has always been clunky and it depends on the underlying library. In most cases it pays off to deal with the timezone separately instead of relying on `strptime()`.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as duplicate.. The issue was because of the timezone, not leading 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python date handling has always been a little light in the timezone handling department (it's a complicated problem). You can implement your own derived `tzinfo` class from the abstract base class provided in the standard library if you only have a small subset of them that need to be handled—I've done it before and it's not too hard—**or** you can use something like the third-party `dateutil` module recommended in the documentation at the end of the [`tzinfo` section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) which handles a much larger number of them.

Anyway, you can get `dateutil` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/py-dateutil/) or you can simply install it from an OS command line with `pip install py-dateutil`.

```
from dateutil import parser

t = parser.parse('May 17, 2018 3:10 AM PDT')
print('t: {!r}'.format(t))  # -> t: datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 17, 3, 10)
```